# APN ( apple push notification ) using expo cli not able to access the custom data

Tags: react-native, expo, apn

i using APN (Apple push notification ) for expo react native app,
i sending push notification using php code from server, with notification i am sending custom data reacordid. , when i am try to use that use recordid, app is getting closed.

Below image is the response of APN

[image]

in the above image pancel marked custom data recordid want use in the app, if am using that recordid app getting closed, how to use that recordid variable in app ?

```
notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
    setNotification(notification);
    let id = 1;
    let str= null;
    alert("notf:: values:"+JSON.stringify(notification));
    
     
    
    if (Platform.OS === 'android'){
        id = notification.request.content.data.recordid;
    }  if (Platform.OS === 'ios'){{
        // ios platform 
        let trigger:any = notification.request.trigger;
    
    //    id = notification.request.trigger.payload.recordid;//not working
        id = trigger.payload.aps.recordid; // check this
        
    }
```

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: code is shared now plz check